# what is the best way to trigger a user thread from a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a module in kernel in which on a particular event/count i want to wake a user thread that will read some data from kernel module via proc fs.

I am trying to send a RT signal from the kernel module to the user thread that is in sleeping state. The signal will call its handler and that will further read the data/buffer from kernel and store it to the files.

I am facing some unknown issue using this approach, after sending the signal the system gets hanged and everything stops.

Please tell me if I am using correct method (using signals) to trigger a user thread from kernel module. If it is correct then what would be possible root cause of the lockup issue.

is there any batter way that I can use to implement such functionality... Please suggest/help.

**KERNEL MODULE :**

```c
static int send_signal(int data)
{
    int ret;
    struct siginfo info;
    struct task_struct *t;

    /* send the signal */
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
    /* I have tried 44 and 30 but both are not working */
    info.si_signo = sig_num;
    info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;
    info.si_int = data;

    if (!g_user_pid) {
        printk("error seding signal, pid is not configured");
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    rcu_read_lock();
    t = pid_task(find_pid_ns(g_user_pid, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID);
    if (t == NULL) {
        printk("invalid pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    printk("sending value %u to pid %d\n", info.si_int, (int)t->pid);
    ret = send_sig_info(sig_num, &info, t); /* send the signal */
    rcu_read_unlock();

    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("error sending signal\n");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**PS** : I am calling this function from interrupt context.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create device file by your kernel module. Reading from this file is blocked until driver puts data. In this case, user space application can open and read from device file data without any sleeping and catching signals.

**Update:** [Here](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html?page=2) you can find example for creating read-only device file. You should add waiting logic in `hello_read_proc()`, this will generate block for reading.

Comment: Thanks!

Can you explain how to implement such thing. or share a link to understand this..

Comment: @PankajGupta Explaining how to do this from scratch will take half a book or more. I suggest you get a book about writing Linux device drivers.