# What is the best way to control (sleeping and running) of a user thread from a kernel module, based on some condition

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to trigger a user thread from from __schedule() function based on following condition - 
I have a static count (unsigned int) in __schedule(), and in every call of __schedule() it gets increased by one. every time when this counter gets equal to 10000, tell a user thread to do some work and after completing that work that user thread goes in sleep/wait again.

I have already tried using signals and blocking process on opening of a proc file.. but these methods are not working properly and causing random lockup issues in the device..

Please suggest if there is a batter way to do this thing or please tell me where i might be doing wrong that can cause this lockup.

Comment: `I have already tried ... blocking process on opening of a proc file.` - This is an attempt to implement approach from [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33214836/3440745), isn't it? Please, provide more information about you problems with this attempt (kernel code, user code, what exactly happens when you use them and so on).